# sending text file as they are

Tags: netbeans-6.9

I have setup a Netbeans project having as development host a remote machine. My application runs on top of few text files acting as configuration. When these files are sent to the remote files they are encrypted or modified (I saw the file content in the remote directory that Netbeans use for building and it is a sequence of unreadable chars).

What I can do to prevent that only for these text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the folder "Important Files" under my project and I called "Add Item to Important File...". After that I cliked "upload" and the same folder structure was recreated without any problem.

I like NetBeans.